# How to write user responses in recast.ai chat bot to google sheets

Tags: chatbot, google-sheets-api, sap-conversational-ai

Recast.ai gave me an opportunity to create smart enough bots for free. But since I am greenhorn in the field I found it difficult to develop any custom inegration

I want my bot to write recognized user inputs in particular cell in google forms or google sheets (doesn't matter)

How can I do it? Is there a special link or API to write the value to google forms?

Answer (score 0):

Google offers APIs for almost all of their products. For forms you can use their API to create edit forms https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/

You will need to call webhooks from the builder to your API (in NodeJS for example) this app will then requests the Google form API to edit your form :)